# MitreId Client authentication filter configuration

Tags: java, filter, struts, openid

i am fairly new to the struts environment and i have been looking around for this kind of thing but cannot find it anywhere else. 
my problem is that i need to configure the OIDAuthenticationFilter. although there is an example in the MitreId website, i cant seem to translate it into the framework i am using which is struts.

what is in the example that i have seen is using some kind of spring security which i am not sure how it works but i understand what it is doing/configuring:

https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/wiki/Client-configuration

the code is too large and i am not going to paste it here for that reason...

in my code, in web.xml is have the following so far:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.something.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and the authentication filter calss is extending the OIDAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OIDCAuthenticationFilter {


public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

}
```

}

i know how to use it in struts and setting the rest up in web.xml, but what i dont know is how do i translate what the example is doing or how it is doing to the way i am doing. as i can see, many things are given values and many classes have parameters being set in the example.

thanks :)

Comment: Do you have any problem in the way you are doing?

Comment: Sorry i am not sure what you mean, but if you mean the framework i am using then no i haven't got a problem. i just dont know how to configure the filter that is all.

Comment: Please narrow the problem down some more. As it stands this question can't be reasonably answered. Are you getting any Exceptions? Any log messages? Do you log out your exceptions at all?

Comment: no, i was not getting any error at all, i just wanted to know how to transform that spring security into pure java when it comes in filters. i have figured it out now and it isn't hard at all its just a simple transformation inserted into init() method in the filter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at it for a few days, i have analysed the filter configurations in the link given. i have come to a conclusion that all i had to do is to instantiate the objects needed to configure the filter, and finally set the objects in the filter. this would then look similar to the configuration in the link which uses spring security. but of course, instead of beans i would use java.

here is what it looked like in the end:

```
this.setAuthenticationManager(new OAuth2AuthenticationManager());
this.setIssuerService(new StaticSingleIssuerService());
this.setServerConfigurationService(new StaticServerConfigurationService());
this.setClientConfigurationService(new StaticClientConfigurationService());
this.setAuthRequestOptionsService(new StaticAuthRequestOptionsService());
this.setAuthRequestUrlBuilder(new PlainAuthRequestUrlBuilder());
```

and from here, simply by doing a

```
this.get....();
```

you would then be able to get the object you created above as new and configure according to the link that was given as there are sets and gets for everything.

i did not think it would be that simple as it is the first time i deal with filters and they sound more complicated than they actually are.

Comment: oh, and i forgot to mention that this is done in the init() method in the filter class. there is a doFilter() method which is called when the filter is called, and the init() method is called when the filter is first initialised.